# Make cluster in leaflet in R only if the point are in the same lat and long?

Tags: r, leaflet, latitude-longitude

How can I do a cluster in leaflet for the points with the same latitude and longitude?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a look at this post about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: Is it the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632210/how-to-set-cluster-if-elements-are-at-same-place-or-stacked ?