# How to set cluster if elements are at same place or stacked?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new for Leaflet, I am looking for marker cluster solution.
I have elements on the map, but few elements are located at the same place so they are hiding behind and on map it looks like there is only one element.

**What I need** : I need marker cluster only if elements are stacked/located at the same place.

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: Does https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster not do what you need? If not, show us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) will solve your problem if you tune the `maxClusterRadius` option (number as small as possible)

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ maxClusterRadius: 1 });
```

This option (defaulted to 80 pixels) says how near markers should be from each other before clustering them.

Comment: I used `maxClusterRadius: 0` to get only those which are located on the exact same place, and not just super super close to each other.  Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction